# Log4j2 - overwrite existing log file configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a set of maven projects, with one `logging`, that defines the dependencies to log4j2

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

as also contains the `log4j2.xml`, with a set of logger appender configurations.

Now I want to overwrite this `log4j2.xml` in a project to e.g. change the log level, as defined in the `logging/log4j2.xml` configuration.

How can I do this ?

I tried to simply add a new `log4j2.xml` in the project classpath (`src/main/resources`) - which seems to be ignored.

I tried to add the new config file via `-Dlog4j.configuration=src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`, but this also seemed to be ignored.

What is the way to use a custom configuration file over a already predefined ?

Comment: In this case, you can use SLF4J to override all the existing loggers. However , you can still change the log level in the configuration log4j2.xml, if I understand your rrequirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2 looks for `log4j.configurationFile` system property, not `log4j.configuration`. So try `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`.

Comment: this does help - i can see the creation e.g. of another log file, when specified in the local `log4j2.xml` - still the log level seems to be not taken into account, but i assume this is a different problem I need to find out.